# How to solve the issue : Deprecated: __autoload() is deprecated?

Tags: magento-1.9, php

Deprecated: __autoload() is deprecated, use spl_autoload_register() instead in C:\wamp64\www\magepro\app\code\core\Mage\Core\functions.php on line

[image]

My php version : 7.1.29

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you please try to change __autoload function to spl_autoload_register after clear cache and remove var directory

```
/app/code/core/Mage/Core/functions.php on line 60
```

[source](https://community.magento.com/t5/Magento-1-x-Version-Upgrades/Can-t-run-Magento-1-9-4-0-on-PHP-7-2-using-Mage-app/td-p/120745)

Let me know issue resolved with it or not ?

Comment: Hey, I tried this and ended up with the error afterwards: Fatal error: Cannot redeclare spl_autoload_register() in /app/code/core/Mage/Core/functions.php on line 69 ... any ideas what I can do to fix this?? Using PHP Version 5.6.40

Comment: magento version ?

Comment: Thanks for quick reply! Magento ver. 1.9.3.6

Comment: I've also tried upgrading the PHP to 7.0.33 and 7.1.33 but the issue continues